# Android: How to use the onDraw method in a class extending InputMethodService

Tags: android, keyboard, ondraw

I have class that extends `InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener`

I want to use:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    paint.setTextSize(25);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);

    List<Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
    for(Key key: keys) {
        if(key.label != null)
            canvas.drawText(key.label.toString(), key.x + (key.width/2), key.y + 25, paint);
    }
}
```

Some 3rd party keyboards have more than one character on each key. For example: 1 top on "q" key.
I want to set for example 1 top on "q" key. Please help me.